# How can I overwrite on files explicitly

Tags: r, dataframe, updates, overwrite

I want to update column 8 of a dataframe in XLS file. I use this condition for update.

```
df1$V8[which(df1$V8 == 'NO' & mlearn %in% inflection_points)[1]: length(df1$V8)] <- 'YES'
```

This updates object df1 on R studio but doesn't overwrite the orignial file unless I save a new file with a new name. I need to know how can I update the original file explicitly without the need to save a new file of updated dataframe. The file should keep its original name as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could delete the old file before writing to it:

```
file_name <- "test.xls"
library(WriteXLS)
# delete the file
unlink(file_name)
# write the updated data to same file
WriteXLS(df1, file_name)
```

Comment: Is deletion the only way to do it? Can't I just open the file, replace the content and close it?

Comment: In my experience, it's often faster to delete first and rewrite than overwrite and the result is the same but you can go the safe way by writing on another name then delete the old file and rename the new file. This way if your R is killed after the delete you do not lose the data.